# Simplification of a trilogarithm of a complex argument

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, special-functions, polylogarithm

Is it possible to simplify the following expression?
$$\large\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-e^{\xi\,\left(\sqrt3-\sqrt{-1}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{12\,\xi}\left(\sqrt3+\sqrt{-1}\right)}\right)$$
where
$$\large\xi=\frac{\sqrt[3]3}6\sqrt[3]{27+\sqrt3\,\sqrt{243-\pi^6}}$$
and $\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3(z)$ denotes the [imaginary part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html) of the [trilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html).

Comment: [Looks like 1/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Im%5BPolyLog%5B3%2C-Exp%5B3%5E%281%2F3%29%2F6%2827%2BSqrt%5B3%5DSqrt%5B243-Pi%5E6%5D%29%5E%281%2F3%29%28Sqrt%5B3%5D-I%29-Pi%5E2%2F%2812*3%5E%281%2F3%29%2F6%2827%2BSqrt%5B3%5DSqrt%5B243-Pi%5E6%5D%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%28Sqrt%5B3%5D%2BI%29%5D%5D%5D)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Step 1**: Note that the trilogarithm argument
$$z=e^{2\pi i x}=-e^{\xi\,\left(\sqrt3-\sqrt{-1}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{12\,\xi}\left(\sqrt3+\sqrt{-1}\right)}$$
lies on the unit circle.

**Step 2**: Use [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)
$$\operatorname{Li}_n(e^{2\pi i x})+(-1)^n\operatorname{Li}_n(e^{-2\pi i x})=-\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}B_n(x),$$
where $B_n(x)$ is the $n$th [Bernoulli polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Explicit_formula). Of course, here $n=3$.

**Step 3**: Simplify.

---

I am pretty sure this will give you the answer $\frac12$ of @VladimirReshetnikov .